# How to add html to an aspx C# codebehind page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have access to a server with aspx pages. I need to add a title, parapgraphs, etc to a page. The page currently only has the following line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Access.Login" %>
```

I do not have access to the CS files, just the DLL. Anyway, when I try to add any html to the document nothing changes. I am able to change the CSS, and if I remove the "inherits" then whatever HTML I have gets displayed, but when the "inherits" is there only the default page gets displayed and none of my additions.

Admittedly I am new to ASP and moreover I am not trying to become a guru just to add some HTML to a page, but any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the Site.master page?

Comment: you add html as strings to the code behind as strings depending on what you are doing. You can also add html directly to the aspx file. So it really depends on what you are tyring to do, could you elaborte on that and post a little more code?

Comment: Perhaps the page requires you to be authenticated before you'd see the content?

Comment: @Spacemancraig, I just want to take this page, which is only one line at the moment, and add something/anything to it. A paragraph, a line, doesn't matter. I just want to be able to modify the page in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your Page_Load embedded in the .aspx and add controls that way:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Access.Login" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            Controls.Add(whatever);
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Try this if the above does not work -->
<script runat="server">
        new protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
                Controls.Add(whatever);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You can also just inherit from Access.Login unless it is sealed and replace your Inheritance attribute with "MyClass"...

Comment: +1 for suggesting inheritance. ofosho: try this first before doing anything crazy, like my answer...

Comment: The following link might contain some more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163445.aspx

Comment: @gangelo, I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. I can create/inject HTML with JS anyway. I am just trying to see if there is a quick solution to being able to just add html to the file.

Comment: @ofosho: you'd have to show us an example of how you are trying to add your controls (via the methods I've posted).  This does not seem that hard, but I am flying blind.

Comment: @gangelo, I want something simple. The goal would be to take:<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Access.Login" %> and just add <p>Some Text</p> to the page.

Comment: @ofosho, what could be simpler than just inheriting Access.Login if it is not sealed?  Injecting HTML via JS would be my last resort.  If it is a question of knowing how Access.Login is coded, just use Reflector.

Comment: @gangelo, please pardon the ignorance, I believe sealed is no source? If so, yes. I tried the code you gave me, but the controls I add just end up replacing the whole page. Could you elaborate on "inheriting Access.Login"? Thanks

Comment: @ofosho: try the second example above.  Reflector would let you look in Access.Login class to get an idea what's going on (http://www.reflector.net/); this is like trying to land a plane with no instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, I'm afraid this is not possible. .NET is a single-inheritance language/framework. So when it says Inherits="Access.Login" that means you can only have it use Access.Login OR your code-behind, but not both.

That said, you could jump through some crazy hoops to accomplish your goal. Like create a brand new "wrapper" page, then in the code-behind fire off an http request to the page you want. Load the response, which will just be a really long string into a 3rd-party DOM parser, or if you're confident you're getting 100% valid XML back, use .NET's built-in XmlDocument or XDocument to parse the page, find your html elements, make your changes, then do a Response.Write with your modified content.

And that's a real-life example of going around your elbow to get to your...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain this will work, but you could have a code-behind file inherit from Access.Login and use the new (override will not work if Page_Load isn't marked as virtual) keyword with Page_Load. Then you could use Inherits="YourAssembly.NewLogin".

The part I am not sure about is whether or not asp.net uses the page class or your subclass to call the Page_Load method. If page_Load was virtual, it wouldn't matter, but since it isn't the new will only be called if the page is cast into your subclass. It is worth a try though.