# how to add HTML to deployed app aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

**Issue is SOLVED: Problem is that it is a pre-compiled web page project and to update the look/feel of the page it will need to be recompiled from source.**

Deployed .Net application on IIS7.5, I only have access to the *.aspx files not the *.cs files or any other files that came with the project.  The *.aspx pages start with the following (just one example):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="blue.cs" Inherits="p9.cblue" %>
```

From everything I had read I should be able to just insert HTML markup, or insert JS, or follow the advice given in [How to add html to an aspx C# codebehind page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630095/how-to-add-html-to-an-aspx-c-sharp-codebehind-page) @stackoverflow

I tried to remove the Inherits and the markup still wouldn't render in the browser.

I tried to insert the following JS right after the body tag in the aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("TEST");</script>
```

It didn't show up.

I tried the suggestion given in the above link:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("TEST"));
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Try this if the above does not work -->
<script runat="server">
        new protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
                Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("TEST"));
            }
        }
</script>
```

and neither of those methods worked either.  I did restart the web server between attempts.  I did even recycle the app pools between attempts.  I did restart the browser to get away from caching issues.  No joy.

I have to be missing something.  It's inconceivable that it is so difficult to add some HTML to an aspx page.  Seems like folks would need to do this quite frequently.

Once again, I don't have access to the *.cs files please don't respond with suggestions that require edits of the *.cs files.  I also realize that I could use .Net Reflector to get the *.cs back out of the DLL and rebuild the solution from it.  However, I shouldn't have to do any of this.  I should be able to just add whatever markup I need to the *.aspx file and be done with it.

EDIT: One more piece of information which may or may not be relevant (I am not a dev so I am not sure on this).  The directory where the app is located contains the *.aspx files.  The directory on the file system where the images are located that are pulled into some of the pages the app renders does only contain a Default.aspx file which contains "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!"

Comment: restarting your browser is not sufficient to clear the cache, have you actively cleared the cache? (e.g. Ctrl-F5)

Comment: Do you know what kind of web app this is? MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: Dirk good point, but Ctrl-F5 didn't change anything either, still doesn't render @Zishan it's Web Forms without any actual forms, there's logic to retrieve data from an SQL server and pass it to the web page where it's rendered using JS.

Comment: My guess is it's a precompiled webpage, right? If so, the contents of the aspx files are precompiled as well: everything is in the DLLs. You can edit your aspx files all you like, but they won't do anything.

Comment: If the page is rendered by JS, I think I'd start with looking into the JS code and making a few changes to that to see if the rendering changes. Perhaps there's a some piece of code in JS that clears all the elements before rendering new ones?

Comment: @Mr Lister Yes you are correct, it's precompiled which should have been obvious to me as soon as I saw the Default.aspx, sigh, so I suppose the only way for me to add markup is to rebuild the solution from Reflector ouput?

Comment: @RealityExtractor I hope so. I never undertook any serious effort to reverse-engineer an entire project, but the source that I have seen coming out of Reflector wasn't pretty. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like multiple folks have pointed out in comments, this was a precompiled web application and had thus be rebuild.

In the future, or for other folks looking at this page, this issue can be avoided by building the solution as a web page and ensuring that during the Publish Web Site step the "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" checkbox is selected.  This will allow you to change the markup and client-side code later without having to recompile the site.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("Woot woot!");
        };
    </script>
```

to end of head tag in .aspx file and try again.

//Edit: What kind of project is it you have deployed? E.g. Web Setup Project or One-click publish?

Comment: your script didn't result in an alert box being shown.  I am not sure how the project was deployed I didn't create it.  Probably not one-click though because I doubt that the coders had access to the server.

Comment: If its all in a dll it a web setup project. Then you have to rebuild the project from the development machine to get any changes on the deployed server.

Answer (score 1):

My bets are on a caching issue. Your example code does not come through, but as long is you don't put the HTML code between ASP tags (because they are parsed by IIS before serving the resulting HTML), it should appear as you describe.

you can clear the IIS cache by running iisreset.exe from the commandline on the server

you can clear the browser cache locally, e.g. by using the Ctrl-F5 key combination

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but as Mr Lister in one of the comments stated the problem is actually that the page is precompiled.  No idea how I missed something this obvious.

Comment: glad you got it solved; I always use updatable precompilation, so you can still change aspx pages as you describe. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx